# About (P=>Q) = ((not P) or Q)

Tags: logic

**Is
(P=>Q) = ((not P) or Q)
a definition or a convention or a theorem?**

If it's a theorem, how to prove it   without the truth table

Can accept the following reasoning?

**let's show that from P => Q we can deduce ((not P) or Q)**

Suppose P => Q, By the absurd, if not ((not P) or Q). We, therefore, have P and (not Q).
Then, because P and (P => Q), implies Q. We get both Q and not Q, ie a contradiction.

Reciprocally,

**let's show that from   ((not P) or Q) we can deduce P => Q**

- suppose Q. Then P => (P and Q) => Q, so P => Q
- suppose not P. Then (not Q) => ((not Q) and (not P)) => (not P), and finally P => Q

Finally from ((not P) or Q), we can deduce (P => Q)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3583323

Comment: Your proof is correct, but note that this is just a more cumbersome way of stating the same you would see in a truth table.

Comment: David  I wanted to avoid the truth table because I had to be convinced of why does false imply everything

Comment: can be a theorem or a definition

Comment: see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642912/understanding-of-material-implication) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184524/interpretation-of-logic-equivalence-p-rightarrow-q-leftrightarrow-sim-p-vee-q)

Comment: See [Material Implication](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Material_Implication). There is a [simple proof of it](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Material_Implication/Formulation_1/Forward_Implication)

Comment: Thank's for all. I read the links, there are those who take it for a definition and others for a theorem